# Wtiring xml with muliple root elements for StaxEventItemWriter

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I have input xmls file with following structure. I'm able to read Header, Data and Trailer using three different steps with in job and persiting data in database. I'm able to read data from database and write these elements in three different out put files, however, I need to create the output file with same structure as of input file. How to combine Header, Data and Trailer and create output xml file using StaxEventItemWriter?
Update - There will be only one instance of Header and Trailer, the Data element will 1 to n.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootelement>
    <Header>
        <element1>value</element1>
        <element2>value</element2>
    </Header>
    <Data>
        <element1>value</element1>
        <element2>value</element2>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <element1>value</element1>
        <element2>value</element2>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <element1>value</element1>
        <element2>value</element2>
    </Data>
    <Trailer>
        <element1>value</element1>
        <element2>value</element2>
    </Trailer>
</rootelement>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the header and footer callbacks in the `StaxEventItemWriter`.  The use case you're describing is exactly what it's for.  Your root tag name would be rootElement, then you'd implement two `StaxWriterCallback`s, one for the header and one for the trailer.  You can see an example of the header in action in the unit test found here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxEventItemWriterTests.java#L347

You can read more about the `StaxWriterCallback` in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/xml/StaxWriterCallback.html